# What Kanai's Cube recipes are not listed?

Tags: diablo-iii

There is a help section in the  Kanai's Cube tab that shows 7 pages of different recipes.

[image: Cropped screenshot of Kanai's Cube and the help section]

I know that you can also put in a Puzzle Ring and that will open a portal to The Vault.

Are there others?

Comment: I don't know, but I just discovered that extracting a legendary power from a gemmed item returns the gem to you, just like when you salvage a gemmed item.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you have said, you are able to place a [Puzzle Ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/puzzle-ring) inside Kanai's cube, hit transmute and a portal to the [Treasure Realm](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Realm) will be opened. Likewise if you place a [Bovine Bardiche](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bovine-bardiche), a legendary Polearm, in the cube and hit transmute, a portal that definitely doesn't lead to a [secret cow level](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/diablo-3-cow-level/), definitely won't open, *wink*. These are the only currently known *secret* cube recipes.